# Why those two questions gets diffrent results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Through: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer if I ask with use of graph api:

```
get: ?ids=http://localhost/gbi-bieganie.pl/2013/03/20/kolacja-po-wieczornym-bieganiu-tak-czy-nie/
```

I get different result for the same url, than with use of fql query:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count 
FROM link_stat 
WHERE url = "http://localhost/gbi-bieganie.pl/2013/03/20/kolacja-po-wieczornym-bieganiu-tak-czy-nie/";
```

Can anybody explain me why those queries differ, and how should I do one query that gets correct number of likes of an url, number of its comments, and number of shares?

Comment: How do they differ?  What should the actual result be?

Comment: Tey differ in like_cout. When first one shoes aktualnie number of URL likes, second one shows 0. Sadly, links with localhost gets cleared every now and than, so most of the time both shows 0.